# How to generate and insert datetime into a mysql database (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, insert

Hey I need to insert current datatime into mysql database.. this is the format:

0000-00-00 00:00:00

Comment: There must be dozens of duplicate questions, but I'm having difficulty locating one. If someone can locate an appropriate dupe I'll remove my answer.

Answer (score 6):

Most easily done with MySQL directly using the `NOW()` function.

```
INSERT INTO tbl (datecol) VALUES (NOW());
```

If you need PHP to produce a value other than the exact current timestamp, use the format:

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $some_unix_timestamp);
```

Comment: @Asaf What columns does your `users` table have? If it worked before adding `NOW()` that would imply that your `users` table has only 5 columns - the empty one `''`, `$username, $email, $md5password, $active_code`.

Answer (score 2):

As a MySQL query:

```
INSERT INTO table (fieldname) VALUES (NOW())
```

And wrapped in PHP:

```
$db = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
$db->query("INSERT INTO table (fieldname) VALUES (NOW())");
```

Comment: `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` returns Unix time, an integer, not the correct MySQL date format